# module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'switch_backend' in Django

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been searching the net with no success. I am importing matplotlib into my django 3.2 project and I get the error module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'switch_backend'

```
import matplotlib as plt

plt.switch_backend('AGG')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
```

is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: ```switch_backend``` is from ```matplotlib.pyplot```,  from https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.switch_backend.html

Comment: I am following some tutorial and they imported matplotlib only and usede switch_backend and it worked. results showed

Comment: somewhat depends on which version you have and what version the tutorial used.

Comment: tutorial is using matplotlib 3.2.0 and i am using 3.4.2

Comment: okay i changed everything to reference matplolib.pyplot and it worked. Thanks